# How can I select an drop down menu item with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, automation, watir, watir-webdriver, webautomation

I'm using watir-webdriver to automate and test with an application. In the process I need to click on a drop down and select a value, however watir can't seem to select the  item. Please help?

My code:

```
browser.text_field(:id => "user_username").set "#{username}"
browser.select_list(:id => 'user_date_of_birth_month').clear
puts browser.select_list(:id => 'user_date_of_birth_month').options
browser.select_list(:id => 'user_date_of_birth_month').select "9"
```

HTML:

```
 <label class="sc-font-light sc-text-light next-light-label" for="user_date_of_birth_month
2. When were you born?<span class="inline-help"><span class="content hidden">For information on why we ask for your date of birth, see <a href="http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/1481474-why-do-you-need-my-date-of-birth-" target="_blank">this help center article</a>.</span></span>
```

```
<div class="width_1_2"><select id="user_date_of_birth_month"name="user[date_of_birth][month]">
 <option value="">Month</option>
 <option value="1">January</option>
 <option value="2">February</option>
 <option value="3">March</option>
 <option value="4">April</option>
 <option value="5">May</option>
 <option value="6">June</option>
 <option value="7">July</option>
 <option value="8">August</option>
 <option value="9">September</option>
 <option value="10">October</option>
 <option value="11">November</option>
 <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select a month, year and the gender the site asks for. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
browser.select_list(:id => 'user_date_of_birth_month').option(:value => '9').select
browser.select_list(:id => 'user_date_of_birth_month').option(:text => 'September').select
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks, do i get rid of my "browser.select()option" and "browser.select().clear" or keep thsoe as well? @AlexGolubenko

Comment: @marriedjane875 nope, `clear` is just for multi-selects lists

Comment: ah, ok, um I got one more question...do you happen to know the easiest way to scrape info off of a webpage? @AlexGolubenko

Comment: @marriedjane875 I think that watir is the easiest way if you will parse web-pages with javascript etc

Comment: ok cool is the a short way to explain how to scrape? @AlexGolubenko

Comment: idrk how to parse...i dnt htink :\

Comment: @marriedjane875 first, there are too much info in google. Second, what exactly do you want to parse? You can create question with html of tag that you want to parse and we'll help you with

Comment: okie doke, Im actually doing that now, i was just hoping its was like a simple lined text or somehing :\ @AlexGolubenko

Comment: I checked it out, kinda weird explanation but I'll tag u in the next quest @AlexGolubenko